# FDT 4 Compiling SWF Application ignores new code

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fdt

So, I've been trying to get an AS3 application (pure) to compile for 6 hours, i have made changes to the code, but they are being completely ignored, I've deleted the output swf, then run the compile, and it creates a new swf, but it still has the old content, from the old code.

I've tried reseting the compilers, to no avail.

I've tried using about 10 differnt flex SDKs, to no avail.

I've tried installing 64bit and 32bit versions (i'm on osx), to no avail.

I'm totally stuck, this is supposed to be about 24 hours of work, so far I have spent 6, and achieved nothing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound totally stupid, but, I had exactly the same issue and i found that i had to manually 'save as' every .as i altered or it would just ignore my changes, coming from a Flash Builder background this stumped me for an afternoon,fdt is great for coding, i think itll take me a while before i understand fully how its configuration works I mean its a great piece of gear just wish i was over that stressful first use knowledge gap

Answer (score 0):

Try running `touch` on the source files and recompile.

e.g. from the `src` folder... (in Terminal)

```
find . -name "*.as" -exec touch {} \;
```